# magento 2 : Remove catalog.leftnav from non anchored category page

Tags: magento2, layout, layered-navigation

How to remove **catalog.leftnav** from Only Non Anchored Category page.
I have to required **catalog.leftnav** in Anchored category page only.

I have done code for that,
file path, **`app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_type_default.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/>                
    </body>
</page>
```

But Above code remove left sidebar from Anchor category page also.

Comment: can you move this code to default.xml?

Answer (score 5):

i know this post is old, but i found a simple solution.

go to `Backend > Products > Categories`  chose the category you want to remove `catalog.leftnav` from

then go to `Design` tab, inside  `Layout Update XML`  put `<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/>`

this should remove `catalog.leftnav` from that category only.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally right, you need to change the name of your file from:

```
catalog_category_view_type_default.xml
```

To:

```
catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children.xml
```

Comment: I have try using above file not working yet.

Comment: my code is working fine, i have blank subcategory in anchor category. so issue is blank category.